# Problem with Hyperledger createPeerAdminCard.sh : "Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found""

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, peer

I got the following error when I run the script ./createPeerAdminCard.sh to create a card in my new HLF network (I have 2 networks, 1 work perfectly).

*the error is "Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to execute transaction 85ca1735c6b736494973699c16c018525c1de49cedec584c22987a80b87b0e77: error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found"*

The command which failed is:

*composer network start --networkName iot-network --networkVersion
0.0.3 -c PeerAdmin@iot-network-org1 -A iotnode1 -C iotnode1/admin-pub.pem -A iotnode2 -C iotnode2/admin-pub.pem*

The docker peer logs is the following:

> 2020-04-15 08:43:59.687 UTC [chaincode-platform] func1 -> ERRO 040
>   Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from
>   build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found " 2020-04-15 08:43:59.687 UTC
>   [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 041 Error building images:
>   Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from
>   build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found " 2020-04-15 08:43:59.687 UTC
>   [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 042 Image Output:
>
> ---
>
> ******************** 2020-04-15 08:43:59.690 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 043 start failed: Failed to generate platform-specific docker
>   build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found " error
>   starting container error starting container 2020-04-15 08:43:59.690
>   UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 044 [channeliot1][8fd6d1f6]
>   failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate
>   platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127
>   "/bin/sh: npm: not found

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but hyperledger composer is end of life, I would suggest you don't use it and use the native fabric client sdks and chaincode sdks instead. The community has moved on from composer now

Comment: Thanks @david_k . Do you know where I can find more information on how to replace the composer without reinstalling all the HLF network? At the same time, it would be good if anyone else can solve this issue as I need the network asap.

Comment: Composer was meant to work with any HLF network (although it only tolerated networks greater than 1.1 and didn't support mutual TLS) , it wasn't a HLF network in itself, so you already have an HLF network. Hyperledger Composer did provide a pre-canned simple development fabric to get you started but I would hope you aren't using that and have setup you HLF network yourself and at the latest level of 1.4

Comment: To port your application off of composer you might find this helpful https://davidkel.github.io/docs/Porting/TOC.html